# YouTube API Playground: Error 403 - Quota Exceeded Despite Low Usage

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm encountering an issue while using the YouTube API Playground. After successfully executing three requests, I started receiving the following error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota.",
        "domain": "youtube.quota",
        "reason": "quotaExceeded"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[quotas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPnU0.png)
[traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF8Br.png)

I've checked my quota settings, and it's set to 10,000 units. However, the usage from the console indicates 0%. I'm puzzled as to why I'm encountering this error when my usage is well below the quota limit.

I just tried to get my playlists. Nothing more.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!